# What is the proper form for "cert_identifier" when using "certupdate"?

Tags: server.app

The required options for `certupdate` seem to have changed in macOS Sierra Server or before, and the manpages have not caught up yet.

When trying:

```
certupdate remove -c /etc/certificates/secure.domain.com.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.cert.pem
```

certupdate throws this error:

```
certupdate[92173:961471] Unable to recreate the missing certificate ID for /etc/certificates/secure.domain.com.1234567890123456789012345678901234567890.cert.pem error = 2
```

If you just use `certupdate` by itself you get:

```
certupdate remove [-c cert_path] [-p cert_persistent_ref_base64] -i cert_identifier
certupdate replace -c old_cert_path [-p old_cert_persistent_ref_base64] -C new_cert_path [-P new_cert_persistent_ref_base64] -i old_cert_identifier -I new_cert_identifier
```

which says that now `-i` and `-I` are required, though not mentioned in the manpages or anywhere online that I can find.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to construct a proper cert_identifier for use with either version of `certupdate` and have tried to use `secure.domain.com.[SHA-1]` with and without various extensions, various paths including `/etc/certificates`, but to no avail. I also asked `security` to find the certificate, hoping it would show some kind of clue, but it did not.

The only thing I've found is that asking `serveradmin` about websites reveals a key called `web:defaultSecureSite:mstCertificateIdentifier` which contains a SHA-256 hash and the domain, but no combination I made of that works, either.

Does anybody have any idea how to use `certupdate` now that these options are required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certupdate tool was not really intended to be used manually, it is supposed to be called by a process that watches the System keychain.

The cert identifier is made up of three parts separated by the ':' char they are:      hashtype:hash:"subject"

sha256:0fa41022930ef3d200102d4f0a90e53b250674b9:"my server.com"

The hash portion is the hashtype hash of the DER formatted certificate.

you can get the identifier for the certificates of interest by running the server admin command:
`sudo serveradmin settings certs`

and looking for the identifier key associated with each cert returned.

Comment: One minor correction. The hashtype is currently "SHA-256" per the recently-updated manpage for certupdate. (Sorry it took so long to try this out and verify it. This answer is otherwise correct.)